# What is the correspondence between gauge field terminology and bundle terminology in electromagnetism?

Tags: differential-forms, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, electromagnetism, gauge-theory

In electromagnetism, the electromagnetic field tensor can be expressed as $$F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu.$$

If we let $A= A_\mu dx^\mu$, since $F= \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$, we get that $$F = dA.$$

I just wanted to check that I'd gotten my terminology right: is $A_\mu$ the gauge field, and then $A$ the connection, and $F$ the curvature? I am questioning myself as I thought that $A_\mu$ was called the vector potential in $B = \nabla \times A$. Also, is it sufficient to say that $A$ is the connection if this is right, or is it the connection over a principle fiber bundle etc. I don't know if I'm being ambiguous, and need to be more precise since I am considering these in a particular context, namely electromagnetism.

Comment: In order to make a meaningful distinction between these formulations, you'll need to ask how, precisely, the mathematical objects involved are defined. Appealing to terminology e.g. "$A$ is a connection" isn't sufficient; you'll have to define what, mathematically , a "connection" is. The different formulations will use the same symbols/terms ($A$, $F$, "space", "field", etc.) to denote *different mathematical objects*.

Comment: @Kajelad In electromagnetism, $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + ieA_\mu$. I am confused because in one book I am reading, Baez, $D_\mu$ is called the connection while $A_\mu$ is called the vector potential, where a connection in this context is a way to differentiate sections. However, I have oftentimes heard of $A = A_\mu dx^\mu$ referred to as the connection. I am not sure what I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Do any of these sources *define* what they mean by "connection"? Different authors can and often will use different terminology, especially in this context; that's why I suggest going by definitions instead. Also, sections of *what*?

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical terminology, the word "connection" sometimes refers to the differential operator $\nabla:\Gamma(E)\to \Omega^1_M(E) = \Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)$.
But if you choose a reference connection $\nabla_0$, or perhaps if there already is a preferred reference connection (like the trivial one $\partial$ in a trivial bundle or a local trivialization of a bundle), then you can write any connection as
$$\nabla = \nabla_0 + A$$
for some $A\in \Omega^1_M(\text{End}(E))= \Omega^1_M(E\otimes E^*)$. For this reason we sometimes write $\nabla_A$. And since, once the reference is chosen, $A$ determines $\nabla_A$ completely by the above formula, the word "connection" sometimes refers to $A$ as well!

Then there is the picture in the principal bundle (say with structure group $G$). A "connection" can be defined as a certain kind of 1-form $A\in \Omega^1_P(\mathfrak g)$ with values in the lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of the lie group $G$. This is equivalent to the stuff on the vector bundle $E$ in some sense, and the $A$ here on $P$ has a direct relationship with the $A$ defined before.

The short answer is that "connection" refers to many equivalent objects.

In physics terminology, the $A$ is the vector potential for the electromagnetic field. And in the gauge theory formulation of electromagnetism, $A$ is a connection on a bundle as above.